# how to add AM or PM in PostgreSQL in date format itself?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mi:ss AM'), 
     'yyyy-MM-dd HH12:MI:SS AM') from dual;

This works fine in oracle but not in Postgres.

Comment: What did you try so far? Oracle <> PostgreSQL, check the manual

Comment: I tried everything. The question is simple. Date with meridian indicator in timestamp without time zone datatype. There was no need to do a -1  on my question.

Comment: The query makes no sense to begin with. You are converting sysdate to a formatted `varchar` just to convert that varchar back to a `date` which `sysdate` was to begin with.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of `sysdate` you should use `current_timestamp`, or `now()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh12:mi:ss AM')
```

Comment: I know that it will work just fine if I use to_char but the problem is that I want the AM or PM format in date data type itself. IN oracle the default date format is 12 hour with AM PM appended. But in postgresql this is not the case. So please help if you can. People just do a -1 on my question without understanding it.

Comment: @alpha_calling you mean that if you SELECT SYSDATE in oracle you get the date in AM/PM format, and if you SELECT current_timestamp in postgresql, without to_char, it won't?

Answer (score 1):

**A table for add AM or PM format itself.**

create table date_tbl 
          (
           id serial,
           Date_time varchar (30) default  TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM') 
           )

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function to accept time stamp with AM/PM over PostgreSQL

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')